# How to remove SMask automatically added by iText?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When I place a transparent PNG image into the PDF I create, iText (version 5.5.10) creates a soft mask for it automatically. However, in some circumstances, I need to remove this mask (or keep iText from generating it in the first place) because, as the PDF specification clearly states, this mask overrides any other current soft mask in the graphics state and I definitely need the latter one to prevail.

```
if (<my-condition> && picture?.ImageMask != null)
  picture.ImageMask = null;
```

doesn't work because passing `null` throws an exception (iText apparently tries to use the value provided without any checking and this leads to a null reference).

Comment: If you don't want iText to create a SMASK, simply use images without transparency! In such a case, therefore, simply do some image preprocessing removing transparency and replacing the transparent parts according to your requirements.

Comment: Well, I may have to revert to this but I wouldn't say this is an approach I like. Note that these are not a few manually created pictures that I can preprocess easily. It's part of a production system where they arrive in great numbers and need to be handled accordingly. Doing costly preprocessing instead of simply being able to null out an existing variable, well. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, dear me, my bad, I stand corrected, although I browsed the documentation, the obvious solution escaped me first. There *is* a boolean:

```
if (<my-condition> && picture.Smask)
  picture.Smask = false;
```

Comment: Ok, sometimes it's easier than imagined... ;)

Comment: I looked around the letter M for mask and didn't note it among the S, although it's obvious in hindsight, of course... :-)